# How to compare any value with Z_PK of Coredata Entity?

Tags: swift, core-data

My app has to support offline that is why i have CoreData, All my PK will be managed my server DB. Now all local updates/insert while one is in offline i need some PK.

So what is best way?

## 1 Should I add one column as my local PK with value as DATE-Time?

## 2 Can We use Z_PK of that entity?(some one said here on stack that apple's is recommendation to not use Z_PK)

For #2 I can get Z_PK value, but not sure how to compare it in predicate to fetch that record.

Any Suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: never use Z_PK from coredata. In fact you can't use it. The attributes you're creating can only be managed by you and updated. Try creating a new column with date time and use that. or also you can store your updates in another entity and whenever user's online you can update the DB on server and can later remove that data from coredata.

Comment: So we should add one extra attribute and use it as PK right?

Comment: What I found is we can access z_ps's value with objectID of our entity.

Comment: date time can be your pk bcz if you check for existing id in coredata you have to loop through. there's no such thing as primary column in coredata, it has to be managed from user side. apple manages it using z_pk

Comment: using z_pk for updation is bad practise.

Comment: Okay Thank you for your valuable suggestion.... (y) I will go with extra attribute for my local use.

Comment: Also if you try to access z_pk be careful. Apple can change its structure on any update. There's no fix to that.

Answer (score 0):

You have the relations with the entities so Why don't you use that?
That would be proven easy and good for comparison in future.

In case you can't use relational entities I suggest you go with the date.

Thanks